# How to make magento 2 indexing fast

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, magento-2.1.3

I have Magento 2.1 shop with about 3,00,000 products, let me know the ways I can make indexing of shop fast

What should be the best server configuration

Comment: Good question! I've been dealing with this for the past few days as well. The last  full index on 2.2.1 took 44 hours. I'll write up a summary of all I've learned and post it asap.

Comment: Can you please state the exact version of Magento you are using?

Comment: Hi @drew7721 Its Magento version 2.1.3

Answer (score 4):

Indexers can be a pain when dealing with large databases. They've been improved over time but there are still some issues that need to be fixed.

[This issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10531#issuecomment-341246906) on the Magento2 repository does give some solutions to the products issues in version prior to 2.

See the comment from @behnamshayani on Nov 1st for a fix for versions 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.10

**Fix:**

*`magento/framework/DB/Query/BatchRangeIterator.php::184`*

```
//wrong
//$object->limit($this->currentBatch, $this->batchSize);

//correct
$object->limit($this->batchSize, $this->currentBatch);
```

Submitted by [@behnamshayani](https://github.com/behnamshayani) on the issue linked above.

Note that this week I tried upgrading to 2.2.1 and the price indexer does get quite long. There are comments on this in the same issue linked above.

It's suggested (by @am2008) that the number of customer groups have an impact on the indexing time.

If you are using the catalogsearch_fulltext indexer that will also be influenced by the qty of attributes you use.

Also, note that if for some reason an indexer is cutoff in the middle of the indexation process (loss of power or connection) then the next indexation will take quite more time (this seems to be a know issue as well).

If you set the indexers to be done on a schedule, M2 does add `_cl` (change log) tables that will monitor changes and only reindex the changed data to the db, so once the initial index is done, recurring ones *should* be faster.

I know this does not really give you an exact fix to the issue but this is what I've gathered so far. Hope it helps.

Comment: did you find any solution for reindex faster? our Magento version is 2.2.5

Comment: Hey @SunilPatel running 2.2.5 as well and the indexers are much faster now. The initial install is longer due to data conversion to JSON format, but the indexing process is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Indexer status**

Depending on whether an index data is up to date, an indexer status value is one of the following:

valid: data is synchronized, no reindex required
invalid: the original data was changed, the index should be updated
working: indexing is in progress
The Magento indexing mechanism uses the status value in reindex triggering process. You can check the status of an indexer in the **Admin panel under System > New Index Management** or manually using the command line.

Indexing modes

Reindexing can be performed in two modes:

Update on Save: index tables are updated immediately after the dictionary data is changed.
Update by Schedule: index tables are updated by cron job according to the configured schedule.
To set these options:

Log in to the **Magento Admin.
Click System > Index Management.**
Select the check box next to each type of indexer to change.
From the Actions list, click the indexing mode.
Click Submit.
You can also reindex from the command line

[image]

**manually using the command line**

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Comment: I don't think you read the question properly. @andrew-smith is asking about how to improve the existing indexing process i.e. make it run faster for thousands of products not about how to re-index.

Comment: This does not answer the question.